# Ownership of Google API keys in the enterprise

Tags: google-maps, enterprise, api-key

When developing a Google Maps or Recaptcha implementation, you can sign up for a free API key using

However, in a large company, you don't want to tie these keys to a developer's gmail account.

Does anyone have suggestions or best practices how Google API Keys should be managed on an organizational level? Who owns them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a gmail account at the group/organization level and use that for the API key.

You may also want to look at [Google Maps Premier API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/) which is more suited for enterprise usage.